# Backbone.Marionette - append itemViews to different container depending on the height of containers

Tags: javascript, dom, backbone.js, coffeescript, marionette

### What i'm trying to achieve

I want to render posts into a timeline. Timeline consists of two columns that i append posts to. I want to be able to append a post to the shorter column. New posts need to be prepended to the first column.

I actually have a working code that solves this problem, but i feel that it's not as efficient as it could be. Marionette by default attaches newly created elements to a `documentFragment` buffer, which is supposed to speed up rendering (less layout changes and such). Also i need to fetch posts after i render the timeline composite view (as both columns need to be attached to DOM to have height).

### What i tried

This is controller responsible for showing view in a certain region in app:

```
class APP.Controllers.Companies extends Marionette.Controller

  initialize: ->
    @vent = _.extend {}, Backbone.Events


  show: ->
    posts = APP.request "posts:collection"
    directoriesPromise = APP.request "directories:all"

    postsView = new APP.Views.Posts.Layout
      vent: @vent
      collection: posts

    postsView.on "render", -> posts.fetch()
    @_wait [directoriesPromise], (directories) =>
      APP.execute "show:main", postsView
```

Please note that i'm fetching posts after i have rendered the composite view, to make sure that collection is initially empty and columns are attached to DOM. Otherwise there are situations where posts collection is cached and is fetched before the view is rendered, which breaks getShortestColumn (see below) function.

_wait is a wrapper for jQuery.wait function.

This is part of Timeline class, that extends Marionette.CompositeView:

```
appendHtml: (compositeView, itemView, index) ->
  @getShortestColumn().append itemView.el


getShortestColumn: ->
  minHeight = Number.MAX_VALUE
  shortest = null

  @ui.columns.each ->
    if $(this).outerHeight() < minHeight
      shortest = $(this)
      minHeight = $(this).outerHeight()

  shortest
```

### The goal

I want to basically keep current functionality but leverage buffering available in marionette. I also want to be able to fetch posts before i show view (as i do with directories), to prevent timeouts or slow connection from hindering user experience.

It would seem i was not clear on what i'm asking about, so here's the question: how do i achieve that?

Any suggestions or solutions are welcome.
Thanksalot.

edit: i forgot to mention that i use Marionette 1.8.6 and unfortunately i can't update.

Comment: you should change 'javascript' tag to 'coffeescript'

Comment: @MatthewA.McFarland coffeescript _is_ javascript. I believe 'coffescript' tag would be appropriate if i asekd about coffescript syntax. This is a javascript question with a javascript/dom problem, it just happens to have code examples written in coffeescript.

Comment: coffeescript is NOT javascript, it compiles TO javascript.

Comment: I personally think its reasonable to have a javascript tag on this question. this question is a question about structure and semantics, not syntax.

Comment: lot of words here but no question mark.  we aren't very helpful without question marks.

Comment: @RobertLevy I assumed the paragraph titled "The goal" was clear enough statement of what i wanted help with. I'm sorry if that was not the case. I've edited the question for more clarity.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of doing fetch in the render event (which is called more frequently than you might expect anyhow), you can override the show method, do the fetch there, and then call the base show method after the fetch is done/failed.

Or better yet, you have a "controller" which is responsible for fetching data and then handing it to the view rather than the view fetching anything itself.

Comment: What do you mean the render is called more often then i might expect? It's being called exactly once.